# How to run tests in a specific order with ginkgo?

Tags: ginkgo

I use ginkgo to write some tests, including:

- books_suite_test.go
- install_test.go
- reading_test.go
- isbn_test.go
- uninstall_test.go

how to run these tests in a specific order as following:

`install_test.go -> reading_test.go -> isbn_test.go -> uninstall_test.go`

I found ginkgo can not ensure the test order. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

User the Ordered keyword in your Describe-block to run the block as a "Ordered Container".
https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#ordered-containers

You should not build tests that rely on tests of other files. Because the dirty answer to your question is that it's possible to put Containers and It-blocks into functions and call them in the order you desire

[Ordered Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLSXW.png)